# Signal gating differences between simulators and architecture

Tags: verilog, simulation, system-verilog

I have a simulation where I change a signal after clock edge and connect it to a D-flipflop.

- I expect the output of the D-flipflop to change at the end of the next clock, but in some simulators it changes simultaneously with the input.
- If I add a #0 statement before changing the signal, it seems to work with all simulators.
- If I move the flipflop from an external module to an internal `always_ff` statement, it seems to work with all simulators.

What is happening here?

Code - testbench.sv

```
module testbench;
logic clk;
logic strb;
logic rdy_out_sv;

UUT2 uut2_instance (
  .clk(clk),
  .strb_in(strb),
  .rdy_out(rdy_out_sv)
);

initial begin
  $dumpfile("dump.vcd"); 
  $dumpvars(0, testbench);
end

initial
begin
  clk = 0;
  forever #(2.5) clk=~clk;
end


initial
begin
    strb = 0;
    @(posedge clk);
    //#0;
            
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
    begin
        strb = 1;
        @(posedge clk);
        //#0;
        
        strb = 0;
        @(posedge clk);
        //#0;                            
    end
    
    $finish;    
end

endmodule
```

and UUT2.sv

```
module UUT2(
    input logic clk,
    input logic strb_in,
    output logic rdy_out
);

always_ff @(posedge clk)
begin
    rdy_out <= strb_in; //Updated to non-blocking after the suggestion from Im Groot
end

endmodule
```

Here is a simulation:

https://edaplayground.com/x/KmSs

It produces the correct result with Aldec and Mentor

[image]

But Cadence and Synopsys (and Vivado) seem to be wrong until i uncomment the `#0;` statements:

[image]

Also, if I move `UUT2` inside the testbench, it seems to be correct for all the simulators

https://edaplayground.com/x/P8Fw

```
module testbench;
logic clk;
logic strb;
logic rdy_out_sv;

always_ff @(posedge clk)
begin
    rdy_out_sv = strb;
end

initial begin
  $dumpfile("dump.vcd"); 
  $dumpvars(0, testbench);
end

initial
begin
  clk = 0;
  forever #(2.5) clk=~clk;
end


initial
begin
    strb = 0;
    @(posedge clk);
    //#0;
            
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
    begin
        strb = 1;
        @(posedge clk);
        //#0;
        
        strb = 0;
        @(posedge clk);
        //#0;                            
    end
    
    $finish;    
end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use nonblocking assignments (`<=`) to model sequential logic in Verilog.  Use this for the `rdy_out` signal in `UUT2` and to drive the `strb_in` input from the testbench.  This will guarantee the same behavior for all simulators compliant with the IEEE Std 1800.

```
module testbench;
logic clk;
logic strb;
logic rdy_out_sv;

UUT2 uut2_instance (
  .clk(clk),
  .strb_in(strb),
  .rdy_out(rdy_out_sv)
);

initial begin
  $dumpfile("dump.vcd"); 
  $dumpvars(0, testbench);
end

initial
begin
  clk = 0;
  forever #(2.5) clk=~clk;
end

initial
begin
    strb = 0;
    @(posedge clk);
            
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
    begin
        strb <= 1;
        @(posedge clk);
        
        strb <= 0;
        @(posedge clk);
    end
    
    $finish;    
end

endmodule

module UUT2(
    input logic clk,
    input logic strb_in,
    output logic rdy_out
);

always_ff @(posedge clk)
begin
    rdy_out <= strb_in;
end

endmodule
```

[image: waves]

Refer to: [EDA Playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/sBbL)

Comment: yes, you are right, i also need to use the non-blocking statements in the testbench too